# Inconsistency in "Answer changed to comment"

Tags: discussion, flagging

I was just wondering about a [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/14073/5918) I answered. My answer was changed to a comment which is fair enough it was basically a link to other info, so my question why is this [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/14075/5918) I flagged to be made a comment any different?
It still only contains links to other information but the flag was disputed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the moderator who didn't act on your flag about [the other answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/14075/21). This is how I was thinking: The question was for product recommendation. The [other answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/14075/21) recommended some specific products. Yours was a more general “here's something you can Google for.” This type of response can be valuable for any question where the asker may not have thought of the right term to look for, but it's not an answer to the question.

That said, the question was [off topic (shopping question, and without relevance to DIY)](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/561/21) and was deleted. It's hard to judge answers well when they are to a question we don't want on the site to begin with. Let's talk abou this again if something similar happens to a better question.

Answer (score 2):

The flags were handled by different moderators. Me in the case of your answer, one of the others in the case of the other answer.

I did see the flag on the other answer and was going to act on it, but work intervened :) When I came back to the site the flag had been cleared so I could see it had been dealt with. I didn't check up on how it had been dealt with - I had no reason to.

I've now converted the other answer to a comment - something perhaps I should have done immediately.

You'll have to wait until the other moderator sees this question to see what he says.

Comment: I thought that might be the case, do you have a superset of rules to follow or are the mods still guided by the faqs for this sort of thing?

Comment: @UNECS - we use the FAQs but there are also other blog posts - the one on shopping recommendations being applicable here - that we also take guidance from.